# Restrict Google News search to United States publications

Tags: search-engine, google-news, news-feed

I have created a Google News feed to display on a website.  It's inexplicably giving me hits from other countries.  Here is the RSS feed code I have tried:

> http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&gl=us&q=tourette&num=30&um=1&ned=us&cr=countryUS&output=rss

The Google Search folklore I have found variously recommends

- gl=us
- ned=us
- cr=countryUS

But I'm getting extraneous hits, such as:

http://gisborneherald.co.nz/localnews/3033186-135/reaching-new-heights-with-tourettes

https://www.infobae.com/america/wapo/2017/10/16/la-estimulacion-cerebral-profunda-puede-reducir-el-sindrome-de-tourette/

http://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/haber/turkiye/848933/Tourette_Sendromlu_gence_cirkin_uyari__Bir_daha_gelme_musteriler_rahatsiz_oluyor.html#

Is there something I can add or fix so that I don't get news items from publications outside the US?

---

The following doesn't give me the international hits I don't want:

http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&num=20&gl=us&q=tourette&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3477l9011l0l9234l17l17l0l11l11l0l214l912l2.2.2l6l0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

Why not?